# Unable to get all the values inside of a 2D array

Tags: python

```
grid = []
for i in range(int(rows)):
    row = []
    for n in range(int(columns)):
        row.append(int(contents[n]))
    grid.append(row)
    
print(grid)
```

The contents array has 9 values inside of it, all of them being strings.
How do I make it so that I get all the 9 values of the contents array inside the grid, so that each value would be present in the grid array, rather than currently just having the first 3 values in 3 rows.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the content array? Also please follow the guidelines before asking questions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please note that these are *not* arrays, but rather, `list`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate variable that increments separately from the for loops, instead of using `n` to grab the values from the list. So, initialize some variable to be 0, like `m = 0` outside of the first for loop, then every time you append `contents[m]`, you would increment `m` by one.

I’m going to use `j` instead of your `n`, and `n` instead of `m` in this example:

```
n = 0
grid = []
for i in range(int(rows)):
    row = []
    for j in range(int(columns)):
        row.append(int(contents[n]))
        n += 1
    grid.append(row)
    
print(grid)
```